# How would I implement this Brute Force Median Search algorithm?

Tags: c++, algorithm

Trying to wrap my head around how this code finds the median of an array of an int as seen in the screenshot from [this booklet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oLRC.png). I have been trying to replicate the code in Code Blocks using C++, as seen in my code.

What basic operations would I need to use? What do I need to change to get my code working?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int A[] = {2,3,4,7,8,9,10,12,15};
int n = ( sizeof(A) / sizeof(A[0]) );
int k = (n/2);

for(int i=0; n-1; i++)
{
    int numsmaller = 0;
    int numequal = 0;
    for(int j=1; n-1; j++)
    {
        if(A[j]<A[i])
        {
            numsmaller = numsmaller + 1;
        }
        else if(A[j]=A[i])
        {
            numequal = numequal + 1;
        }
    }
    if(((numsmaller < k)&&(k<=(numsmaller + numequal))))
    {
        k = A[i];
        cout << k;
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

############ FIXED CODED ######################.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int A[] = {2,3,4,7,8,9,10,12,15};
int n = ( sizeof(A) / sizeof(A[0]) );
int k = (n/2);

for(int i=0;i <= (n-1); i++)
{
int numsmaller = 0;
int numequal = 0;
for(int j=1;j <= (n-1); j++)
{
    if(A[j]<A[i])
    {
        numsmaller = numsmaller + 1;
    }
    else if(A[j]==A[i])
    {
        numequal = numequal + 1;
    }
}
if(((numsmaller < k)&&(k<=(numsmaller + numequal))))
{
    k = A[i];
    cout << k;
    return 0;
}
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your `for` loops are not correct (hint: the `n-1` part).

Comment: The for loops follow the Algorithm as seen in the booklet.. Click on the "this Booklet Link"

Comment: I mean that is not the correct the correct logic (i.e., they aren't doing what you think they're doing -- `n-1` is always true, for the posted code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`else if(A[j]=A[i])` should be `else if (A[j]==A[i])`

You may want to increase the warning level for the compiler.  Usually `-Wall`.

Also, at the point where you perform the `cout << k` you should return or exit - the program is done.

Comment: Thank you.. The problems was in the if statement as you stated.. As well as needing an exit as stated. It started popping up with an error which was fixed by altering the second condition on both For Loops into j <= (n-1) and i <= (n-1)

Answer (score 2):

This algorithm is so inefficient though. Why would you use it to search an array?

You may want to have a look at the [quickselect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect) algorithm. It works so much faster. But you would know that if you actually did the assignment before the due date.

Comment: It is for an assignment due tonight